# Pull request linter

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, pull-request

I'm searching an easy way to have a sort of pull request linter.
Here is what I want to do.

1. One of my colleagues do a pull request.
2. A tool check the quality of the code (respect of the standard PSR2, check of the PHP code).
3. A tool launch the unit testing of this branch.
4. All the results of these tools appears in comment of the pull request.
5. If all is ok, the pull request is assigned to me and I can check it manually.

If I approve and merge the pull request, a new job is trigged on the destination branch to launch unit testing automatically.

I have see tools like Jenkins but I'm not sure I will be able to do that with it, and if what I want to do is called continuous integration.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you have described is exactly continuous integration. Code linters are usually just a part of it running as a separate test step. You need a tool like [BuildBot](http://buildbot.net/), [Concourse](https://concourse.ci/), Jenkins, [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/) for CI. GitLab is the most powerful of them as it has git hosting, issue trackers and continuous integration; you can download install GitLab locally.